# Reseting a counter of a protected/nested variable in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, counter, nested-function

My intention is to create a safe counter and reset it by calling a function. I tried this code:

```
function ZeroCounter () { var c = 0 ; return function() { return ++c } };
```

`const Counter = ZeroCounter();`

But didn't work as I expected. ZeroCounter doens't reset `var C`. I noticed that `function() return` creates a new object.

```
var m = ZeroCounter(); var n = ZeroCounter();
```

`m === n //return false`

I tried a new code for ZeroCounter.

`function ZeroCounter () { var c = 0 ; ret = function() { return ++c }; return ret  };`

In fact, no reasons for new results. So, What can I do to reach my intention: create a resetable nested variable? Or is it not possible in this way?

Comment: where is the part where you like to reset the counter?

Comment: It's not clear what your question is. With this code, `var m = ZeroCounter()`, successive calls to `m` will yield `1`, `2` etc. If you want to be able to reset the count, you need to return an object with 2 methods, one to increment and one to reset.

Comment: `c` is always `0` when you call `ZeroCounter()` and `ZeroCounter()` returns another function. so to call the nested function you have to to `ZeroCounter()()`. Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: The idea is reset a counter, in the terms of question, to put 0 in `var c`. Calling ZeroCounter makes `c = 0`, but seems to create a new counter (keeping the actual counter,  `var Counter`, unchanged. ).

when is asked  m === n, the answer is thay are not equal, they are different counters created by the same function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the parameter of the function and reset to a wanted value.

```js
function counter() {
    var c = 0;
    return function(v) { 
        if (v !== undefined) c = v;
        return ++c
    };
}

const counterA = counter();

console.log(counterA());
console.log(counterA());
console.log(counterA());
console.log(counterA(0));
console.log(counterA());
console.log(counterA());
```

Comment: Wow! Good approximation! With this technique I choice the start point for counting. I would like something more "auto" but, anyway, that is sufficient in many aspects. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Basically, you're re-creating `c` each time you execute `ZeroCounter`. To get around that, move `c` outside of `ZeroCounter`.

```js
var c = 0;

function ZeroCounter() {
    return ++c;
}

var m = ZeroCounter();
var n = ZeroCounter();
console.log(m);
console.log(n);
```

If you want to contain `c` within `ZeroCounter` but still want the effect, use an [Immediately Invoked Function Expression or IIFE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE)

```js
var ZeroCounter = (function () {

    var c = 0;

    return function () {
        return ++c;
    };

}());

var m = ZeroCounter();
var n = ZeroCounter();
console.log(m);
console.log(n);
```

Comment: In this way any another function could change `var c`, that means c is not safe!

Comment: @DanielBandeira only the first version. The IIFE would solve that.